# Javascript parseFloat issue

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I am facing a new problem. I have the below use case.

```
var a = parseFloat(10); // Returns 10
var b = parseFloat(1.62); // Returns 1.62
var c = a + b; // Returns 11.620000000000001
```

I want the `c` to return `11.62`. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var a = parseFloat(10); // Returns 10
var b = parseFloat(1.62); // Returns 1.62
var c = a + b; // Returns 11.620000000000001

console.log(c.toFixed(2))    
Output: 11.62

console.log(c.toPrecision(4))
Output: 11.62
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = parseFloat(10); // Returns 10
var b = parseFloat(1.62); // Returns 1.62
var c = a + b; // Returns 11.620000000000001
console.log(c.toPrecision(4));
```

Output: 11.62